# nsExec to get IIS FastCGI setup

Tags: nsis

Following command line (admin) in cmd provides the result ie. C:\PHP\php.exe:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi "/text:[arguments=''].fullPath"
```

Now i want to implement it using nsExec::ExecToStack as

```
nsExec::ExecToStack "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi $\"/text:[arguments=''].fullPath$\""
Pop $0
Pop $1
MessageBox MB_OK $0
MessageBox MB_OK $1
```

It results ''error''. I have tried to findout the reason behind and google it but unsuccess to get its replication.
Here i am looking for the probable reason behind it and possible solution. Please take it as geniune and sorry for any missings, making it specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
nsExec::ExecToStack ` %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi $\"/text:[arguments=''].fullPath$\" `
```

Comment: can you use `Exec` instead of `nsExec::ExecToStack`

Answer (score 0):

You have a quoting problem.

- the command to execute and its path must be double quoted in the `ExecToStack` argument as shown in the doc :

  ```
  nsExec::ExecToStack [OPTIONS] '"PATH" param1 param2 paramN'
  ```
- i can see that you are trying to escape the double quote for the last argument. NSIS supports 3 different kind of string quoting : double quotes `"`, single quotes `'` and back quotes `` ` `` and both are processed exactly the same way (not like in Perl where single quotes prevent the string interpolation)

Thus you shoud try to invoke your command with another quoting:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack `"%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" list config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi "/text:[arguments=''].fullPath"`
```